# Query gives not result

Tags: postgresql

I have a quite simple table with different values. When I search a specific column no results are given. What could be the error?

For example I search for an "id":

```
db=# select * from table where id = 160000;
 x  | y  | alt  |   lat    |   lon    |   id   
----+----+------+----------+----------+--------
 80 | 80 | 2044 | 46.80125 | 12.99875 | 160000
(1 row)
```

Then I search for all "lat" with this value (limited to 1):

```
db=# select * from table where lat = 46.80125 limit 1;
 x | y  | alt  |   lat    |   lon    |  id   
---+----+------+----------+----------+-------
 1 | 80 | 1365 | 46.80125 | 12.00125 | 31921
(1 row)
```

But with the same search for "lon" I get no result where there should be:

```
db=# select * from table where lon = 12.99875;
 x | y | alt | lat | lon | id 
---+---+-----+-----+-----+----
(0 rows)
```

I did VACUUM and ANALYZE and now I don't know what to do else.

Test case:

```
CREATE TABLE public.table
(
  x integer,
  y integer,
  alt double precision,
  lat double precision,
  lon double precision,
  id integer,
  CONSTRAINT table_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id )
)

INSERT INTO table VALUES
    (1, 1, 0, 46.81375, 12.18625, 1),
    (1, 2, 0, 46.81375, 12.03625, 2),
    (1, 3, 0, 46.18875, 12.03625, 3),
    (1, 4, 0, 46.18875, 12.18625, 4),
    (80, 80, 0, 46.80125, 12.99875, 160000);
```

Comment: Could you please post a test case?  With table definition, insert statements and so on.

Comment: Are you using floating point datatypes? You can't expect equality to work reliably with floating point. Please provide us with your table definition.

Comment: i assume that you used float or so as column type. consider using numeric.

Comment: Question updated. lat and lon are both double precision, interesting that one is found. Which query would show me then the "real" value saved for lon?

Comment: `double` an _approximate_ data type and comparison will not always work the way you think it will: http://floating-point-gui.de/

Comment: Additionally: the value `12.99875` from your sample query doesn't show up in your sample data at all. Is that a typo? Using `where lon = 12.18625` does work.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I forgot that data. I guess I will change the data type to numeric.